# ASUS M5A88-V EVO Downclocking?

Tags: memory, motherboard, underclock

Can the "ASUS M5A88-V EVO AM3+ motherboard" down/underclock 1866 ram to 1333 so I can use a Phenom II for now and not have to switch out ram later when I eventually upgrade the CPU?